# Cannot return Subclass instance from Class.__new__()

Tags: class, python-3.x, instance, python-3.4

Here is the Python 3 code:

```
class Class:
  def __new__(cls, value):
    print(__class__, cls, value)
    return Subclass(value+1, value+2)

class Subclass(Class):
  def __new__(cls, value, value2):
    print(__class__, cls, value, value2)
    return object.__new__(Subclass)
  def __init__(self, *args):
    print(args)
    self.value = args


acctual_instance = Class(1)
print('acctual_instance:', acctual_instance.value, type(acctual_instance))
```

The output:

```
<class '__main__.Class'> <class '__main__.Class'> 1
<class '__main__.Subclass'> <class '__main__.Subclass'> 2 3
(2, 3)
(1,)
acctual_instance: (1,) <class '__main__.Subclass'>
```

Even though we returned `Subclass(2,3)` instance from `Class.__new__(1)`, the `acctual_instance.value` is `Class`' argument 1, not (2,3). Is this the expected behaviour? Why is `Subclass.__init__()` called the second time? How can I return `Subclass(2,3)` instance from `Class.__new__(1)`?

UPDATE:
If `Class` is removed from class `Subclass(Class)` then the output is:

```
<class '__main__.Class'> <class '__main__.Class'> 1
<class '__main__.Subclass'> <class '__main__.Subclass'> 2 3
(2, 3)
acctual_instance: (2, 3) <class '__main__.Subclass'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on `__new__()` is [quite explicit](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) on this:

> Typical implementations create a new instance of the class by invoking the superclass's `__new__()` method using `super(currentclass, cls).__new__(cls[, ...])` with appropriate arguments and then modifying the newly-created instance as necessary before returning it.

This is because a class initialization `Class(1)` is more or less equal to

```
 obj = Class.__new__(Class, 1)
 obj.__init__(1)
```

In your code, you create a fully initialized instance in `__new__()`

```
return Subclass(value+1, value+2)
```

This will call `obj2 = Subclass.__new__(cls, value + 1, value + 2)` followed by `obj2.__init__(value + 1, value + 2)` and then return `obj2`.

This is followed by a call to `obj.__init__(1)`, after returning from `__new__()` as detailed above: The second `__init__()` is invoked with the original argument (`1`). Hence `value == 1`. The initial value set by the first constructor call is overwritten by the second constructor call.

An improved version of your code could be

```
class Class:
    def __new__(cls, value):
        return Subclass.__new__(cls, value + 1, value + 2)

class SubClass(Class):
    def __new__(cls, value1, value2):
        return object.__new__(Subclass)

    def __init__(self, *args):
        print(args)

instance = Base(1)
print(type(instance))
```

Note, however, that version does nothing with `value1` and `value2` passed to `Subclass.__new__()`.

Note also that in `Subclass.__init__()` you should also invoke `super().__init__()`

Comment: That quote is a description of what you *should* do. It doesn't explain the behavior the OP is seeing, especially the two calls to `Subclass.__init__`. (The paragraph that follows the one you quote, however, provides the answer. After `Class.__new__` return an instance of type `Class`, that object's `__init__` is invoked.)

Comment: Read the full answer, please. He instantiates a full instance of subclass in `Class.__new__()` which gives him the first `__init__()` call. The second call is the *usual* call from the initialization.

Comment: @chepner, technically, "Class.__new__ returns an instance of type Subclass, not Class" =))). But I see your point. The answer to my last question then, is that it is not possible to return Subclass instance from Class.__new__. If you comment would have been an answer, it would have been also accepted. =)

Comment: @dhke, the type of acctual_instance is Subclass, but it has Class' value member. Also, invoking super().__init__() does not make any difference since method Class.__init__() is not defined. I'd updated to question to show that is you remove "Class" in "class Subclass(Class):" then everything works as expected.